# jQuery validation plugin - if empty, allow, if not, check required format

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have custom jQuery validation function, but I'm not able to make it working as I want:
If element is empty, I don't want to validate it, but if it's not empty, I want to check, if value is correct.

My custom function looks like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("phoneCZ", function(phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");

        if(!phone_number.match(/^((\+420)|(\+421))??[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{3}$/)){ 
            return (phone_number.length < 1);
        }
        else {        
            return (phone_number.length >= 9);
        }
    }, "Neplatné telefonní číslo");
```

Maybe just some describe:
Allowed formats are:
123456789
+420123456789
+421123456789

If numbers is not in correct format, I return true, if it's length is 0, else return false. I format is matched, I check, if length is at least 9 characters.

Comment: Add `if (phone_number.length === 0) return true;` at the top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method called `optional` which allows you to do this

```
$.validator.addMethod("phoneCZ", function (phone_number, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");

    if (!phone_number.match(/^((\+420)|(\+421))??[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{3}$/)) {
        return (phone_number.length < 1);
    } else {
        return (phone_number.length >= 9);
    }
}, "Neplatné telefonní číslo");
```

Demo:

```js
$.validator.addMethod("phoneCZ", function(phone_number, element) {
  if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
  }
  phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");

  if (!phone_number.match(/^((\+420)|(\+421))??[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{3}$/)) {
    return (phone_number.length < 1);
  } else {
    return (phone_number.length >= 9);
  }
}, "Neplatné telefonní číslo");

jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#myform').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
      phoneCZ1: {
        phoneCZ: true
      },
      phoneCZ2: {
        required: true,
        phoneCZ: true
      }
    },
    messages: {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <input name="phoneCZ1" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="phoneCZ2" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```